# OutOfMemoryException in C# MultiThreading Environment

Tags: c#, multithreading

This relates more to an interview question - I have been asked multiple times of what is the simplest way to get `OutOfMemoryException` in a C# multi-threaded environment. Specifically how can we achieve it in each of the following multi-threaded mechanisms:

1. Async Delegates
2. Spawning a new thread
3. Using Thread Pool
4. Timer
5. Backgrounworker

Comment: I don't see what multiple threads have to do it. The simplest way to get an exception is to try to allocate enormous arrays of large value types...

Comment: "simplest way to get OutOfMemoryException in a C# multi-threaded environment" is a silly question by itself. The simplest way to get an OOM is to do something like `var foo = new long[int.MaxValue]`, no multi threading required.

Comment: IMO that is an awful interview question...maybe bad enough to send me on a never ending bathroom break...

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense.  As others observed, when you want to create an OOM you simply allocate memory (and hold the references) until you create it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - one answer I gave was if you keep allocating work to ThreadPool using a while loop - eventually it will exhaust the allocation and give OutofMemoryException. Was looking for similar suggestions/other ways to answer

Comment: @Patrick That assumes that you're allocating new work faster than the work is being completed.  That's not often the case.

Comment: Agree with the assumption Servy

Comment: The point of seemingly idiotic questions like this is to test the applicant in requirement gathering and application of specification. When presented with the question, the best thing to do is to ask the interviewer to clarify what they mean by "get an OutOfMemoryException". If they say you simply need to have your code generate the exception then my answer below will fall within the spec in any of the provided scenarios.

Comment: people ask more and more ridiculous questions on the interview at least in the UK. it seems to be a trend which is not going to stop any time soon.. however I don't think the question is stupid. this simply exploits how deep your understand of .NET is. for example new thread allocates stack and thread memory block etc..... this question is actually really interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
throw new OutOfMemoryException();
```